# How to block specific urls in Android

Tags: android, mdm

I am developing a parental kind of App in which there is a requirement to block specific urls from all the browsers in the Device. I think this is an old question but couldn't find any solution yet on stack.

Do you have any working solutions. Assumption - The device is rooted.

Regards,
sha

Comment: Since the device is rooted, block the addresses with `iptables`. Look at the [AFWall+](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/) project on GitHub. Otherwise if you want to be able to run you app on unrooted devices, look into creating a fake VPN to block addresses like [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/mobile/secure-wireless).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Will look into it..

Comment: @Sam shouldn't your comment be an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two resources for you:

1. Since the device is rooted you can work directly with [`iptables`](http://www.netfilter.org/). `iptables` will give you very precise control over all coming and going data packets.  Check out open source projects like [AFWall+](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/) on GitHub for `iptables` in action.
2. If you want to be able to run your app on unrooted devices look into creating a fake VPN.  You don't send any data to an actual VPN server, you simply use the VPN API to filter all the information coming and going.  Check out [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/opensource) (whenever they actually share their open source code...) or [OpenVPN](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn) which is what Disconnect builds on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I havent still tried out but seems the second option is perfect in my situation.